Looking for an 80s cartoon set in a canyon where the characters use ropes on grappling guns to move around
Please help me remember this cartoon.
So, there are these guys, maybe in an alien world maybe not, but definitely in a canyon. They all use backpacks that shoot ropes like grappling guns that hook onto the canyon's walls and they slide along these ropes, fighting bad guys who have the same equipment.
It looked like The Centurions, and like MASK, but it was another cartoon. These grappling gun backpacks looked like a really silly way of transportation.

I believe you're thinking of Sky Commanders, which ran for 13 episodes in 1987 as part of The Funtastic World of Hanna-Barbera.  Like many cartoons of that era, including The Centurions and MASK, it had an accompanying toy line and was obviously designed to be very "toyetic".
The action took place on a new continent in the South Pacific, referred to as "The High Frontier"; Wikipedia describes the backpacks that were used for travel:

Travel throughout the new continent is only possible by means of high-altitude flight, or by means of using Laser Cables; a specialized version of a rappelling cord emitted from combat backpacks worn by both Raider and Sky Commander. When used, the cables shoot out from the combat backpacks in the form of energy beams. When contact is made with a solid object, the Laser Cable solidifies into a solid metal cable line upon which travel is possible.

It doesn't say that the action was restricted to a canyon, but since canyons were probably the cheapest way to animate big open spaces where the backpacks would be useful, I'm betting that they spent lots of time in canyons and they all looked like the same canyon.  80's cartoons did love their money-saving optimizations!
